# do organic- compounds can be synthesized from inorganic compounds?illustrare with example

Tags: organic-chemistry

Do you think that organic compound can be synthesized from inorganic compounds? Illustrate with example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course! Friedrich Wöhler, a German chemist, synthesized Urea, a clearly organic molecule since it is produced in every animal and human body, in 1828.

He used different sets of inorganic substances: a combination of cyanic acid and ammonia, a combination of silver cyanate and ammonium chloride, a combination of lead cyanate and ammonia and a combination of mercury cyanate and cyanatic ammonia (which is again cyanic acid with ammonia).

Ever before humanity was sure that organic substances could only be formed by god. Wöhler proved they were wrong.

Comment: Perhaps not really by God. But by means of a living sort of spirit / property (vis vitalis) peculiar to living organisms.

Comment: Hermann Kolbe (1818-1884) ended the concept of vitalism with his synthesis of acetic acid from iron pyrite and carbon (1845).

Comment: Correction: Lampadius (1796) made CS2 from FeS2 and carbon. Kolbe used CS2 and chlorine to make acetic acid. Inorganic ---> organic.